# Is there an easy way to animate a scrolling vertical line in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, seaborn

I would like to have what I would describe as a progress marker that seems pretty common in audio playback utilites. I would  think in matplotlib this amounts to left/right animated `plt.vlines`. My code takes a 2 second array of data and creates an audio time series visualization. I'm struggling to create an animated vertical line that would move across the plot linearly for 2 seconds from 0 to 2.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

font = {'weight': 'bold', 'size': 15}
plt.rc('font',**font)
sns.set_style("darkgrid")

testSeries = np.random.randint(-10, 20, 12000)
testSeries = testSeries - testSeries.mean()


fig,axis = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1,figsize=(18,5),sharex=True)
sns.lineplot(range(0,len(testSeries)),testSeries,  color='#007294')
plt.xlim(0, len(testSeries))
axis.set_xlabel("Time (s)", fontsize='large', fontweight='bold')
axis.set_ylabel("Amplitude", fontsize='large', fontweight='bold')
axis.set_xticklabels(['0', '0.3', '0.6', '1', '1.3', '1.6', '2'],fontsize=15)
fig.tight_layout(rect=[0,0,.8,1]) 
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=-0.01)
sns.despine()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`axvline()` simply returns a `Line2D` object, so you can update its position by using `Line2D.set_xdata()`

```
duration = 2 # in sec
refreshPeriod = 100 # in ms

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
vl = ax.axvline(0, ls='-', color='r', lw=1, zorder=10)
ax.set_xlim(0,duration)

def animate(i,vl,period):
    t = i*period / 1000
    vl.set_xdata([t,t])
    return vl,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=int(duration/(refreshPeriod/1000)), fargs=(vl,refreshPeriod), interval=refreshPeriod)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that the refresh rate is not guaranteed, it depends on the time it takes to redraw the figure. You may have to play around with the `refreshPeriod`.

Comment: That is really nice, but how to get the refresh rate more accurate? Is there a possibiliy to correct for the time it takes for redrawing the figure with the next drawing, such that small differences do not add up?

Answer (score 1):

Interactive mode of `matplotlib` might be useful to you. Here's how you could set it up:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


testSeries = np.random.randint(-10, 20, 1000)
testSeries = testSeries - testSeries.mean()

x = range(0,len(testSeries))
fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1)

line = ax.plot((x[0], x[0]), (0, testSeries[0]), 'k-',linewidth=4)

plt.xlim(0, len(testSeries))
plt.ion()   # set interactive mode
plt.show()

ax.set_xlabel("Time (s)", fontsize='large', fontweight='bold')
ax.set_ylabel("Amplitude", fontsize='large', fontweight='bold')
ax.set_xticklabels(['0', '0.3', '0.6', '1', '1.3', '1.6', '2'],fontsize=15)

for i,serie in enumerate(testSeries):
#comment the following three lines if you don't want to remove previous lines

    for l in line:
        l.remove()
        del l

    line = ax.plot((x[i], x[i]), (0, testSeries[i]), 'k-',linewidth=4)
    plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
    plt.pause(0.01)
```

Output (with previous lines kept):

[image: example]

Output (with previous lines deleted):
[image: example2]

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking to achieve, but it's an interesting solution nonetheless.